# VB.NET : DataGridView Showing 2 Buttons instead of 1 only

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I just cant get rid the 2nd button in the DataGridView, even though I just Initialize 1 button only.

```
Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
MetroGrid7.Columns.Add(btn)
btn.HeaderText = "Security"
btn.Text = "LOCKED"
btn.Name = "btnSearchSecurity"
btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
```

[image]

Comment: Firstly, don't add the column to the grid and then configure it.  Create the object, then configure it, then add it to the grid.  ALWAYS do the configuration first and then display the finished product.

Comment: As for the issue, if you're seeing two button columns then you are adding two button columns, plain and simple.  The code you have shown only creates and displays one column so that's not the issue.  Either you are executing that code twice or you have other code somewhere else that adds another column or you are adding a column in the designer.  The only other possibility is that your system is broken and we can't really help with that anyway.

Comment: hmmm true, will get back to you

Comment: If nothing is obvious, I'd start by placing a breakpoint on that code and see whether it gets hit twice.  The call stack will then tell you where you're coming from each time.

Comment: aghhh! hmmm it seems I placed the code in TextChange event so everytime the text changes it is executing the add gridview button. gonna fix it now. thanks for the guide

Comment: Personally, if I know everything I need to know about a column at design time then I'm adding the column in the designer rather than in code.